# What causes a saved webpage to render differently from its online URL counterpart?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, web

For example, saving [this page](http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html?id=118&security=137&tab=0) as "Webpage, Complete" using Google Chrome and then reloading the local file results in a broken layout with many missing information.

Comment: After saving your page, I noticed that no resources files where saved on my PC i.e. JavaScript, CSS, images, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is dependency on JS and CSS files which you don't have locally.

Just checked source of the page following are the CSS files which are used by page. You dont have this files thats why layout looks distorted

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles/pse/theme.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/styles/pse/print.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles/pse/lofslider.css" />
```

Comment: These CSS files actually get saved locally. Google Chrome modifies the hrefs to point to the local files prior to saving the HTML.